# Переменная в function

Tags: php

есть функция

```
function curl_redir_exec($ch)
  {
  static $curl_loops = 0;
  static $curl_max_loops = 20;
  if ($curl_loops >= $curl_max_loops)
    {
    $curl_loops = 0;
    return false;
    }
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  list($header, $data) = explode("\n\n", $data, 2);
  $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

  if ($http_code == 301 || $http_code == 302)
    {
    $matches = array();
    preg_match('/Location:(.*?)\n/', $header, $matches);
    $url = @parse_url(trim(array_pop($matches)));
    if (!$url)
      {
      $curl_loops = 0;
      return $data;
      }
    $last_url = parse_url(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL));

    if (!$url['scheme'])
      $url['scheme'] = $last_url['scheme'];
    if (!$url['host'])
      $url['host'] = $last_url['host'];
    if (!$url['path'])
      $url['path'] = $last_url['path'];
    $new_url = $url['scheme'] . '://' . $url['host'] . $url['path'] . ($url['query']?'?'.$url['query']:'');

    echo $new_url.' --- '.$http_code.'<br>';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $new_url);
    return curl_redir_exec($ch);
    }
  else
    {
    $curl_loops = 0;
    return $data;
    }
  }
```

мне нужно с функции выдернуть переменную которая крутиться внутри мне ее наружу нужно вытащить это переменная $new_url как лучше ее вытащить наружу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так например http://pastebin.com/Eemmn2Fz